# In Azure, want to send logs of Windows Virtual machines to 2 different Logs Workspace

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-vm

In Azure, want to send logs of Windows Virtual machines to 2 different Logs Analytics Workspace. I have different resource groups that want to collect logs there themselves in Logs Analytics and security logs(custom logs) to centralize(single) Logs Analytics Workspace from different resource groups.

Is it possible to send logs to multi-workspace analytics?

Comment: Are your virtual machines all in Azure or on-premises?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have windows VM, you can setup to send to multiple Log Analytics Workspaces (multi-homing).

Extension is applicable for Azure Virtual Machines. Direct agent can be used for Azure and non-Azure Virtual Machines(on-premise). The agent isn't only for connecting to Azure Monitor. Other services such as Azure Security Center and Azure Sentinel rely on the agent and its connected Log Analytics workspace

If automatic provisioning is On, Security Center provisions the Log Analytics Agent on all supported Azure VMs and any new ones that are created.

> **Note:** Windows agents can connect to up to four workspaces, even if
> they are connected to a System Center Operations Manager management
> group.
>
> The Linux agent does not support multi-homing and can only connect to
> a single workspace or management group.